# Most efficient way to validate domain name in an email field in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, email-validation

I need to have just one validation in the email field, i.e domain name say 'something'.

Example:

```
adarsh.k@something.com -valid
adarsh.k@gmail.com - invalid
```

I have the emailid entered in the textbox stored as given below, Can you let me know the regular expression to have this basic above validation?

```
 var emailId = $('#txtRcpntAdress').val();
```

I am trying to use a reqular expression given below for the pattern.

```
var validDomain = "something";
var pattern = new RegExp("([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])"+"@" + validDomain + "(.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$");
```

It throws an error

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid range in character set
```

Can you please help?

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: what about `.museum` and `.travel` tlds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
   var validDomain = "something";
   var pattern = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.]+@" + validDomain + "(.[a-zA-Z\\.]{2,5})$");
   var emailId = "adarsh.k@something.com";

   if( emailId.match(pattern) )
   {
     // ... email is valid
   }
```

If you want to match the complete domain just change the first two lines:

```
   var validDomain = "something.com";
   var pattern = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.]+@" + validDomain + "$");
```

Comment: it validates: something.com, something.it, something.net, etc... (i suppose this was requested)

Comment: var pattern = new RegExp("([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])"+"@" + validDomain + "(.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$"); i tried this, it said Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid range in character set when i entered 'adarshk' did i miss anything here?

Comment: try with double slashes: `([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])`

Comment: I just updated the regex and it seems to work for me now... ;)

Comment: If at all, my requirement says it should be something.com and not any other like .net, .org etc, can i update the validDomain = "something.com" and remove the last part of the Reg expression? will that work?

Comment: Changing the second line as follow will do the trick: `var pattern = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.]+@" + validDomain + "$");` and obviously you have to set your _validDomain_ variable to `something.com`

Comment: I am trying this, if (emailIds.match(pattern) == false) {
        isValid = false;
    }  No matter what I give as input say ada,adsaf the control isnt going inside this loop! Anything i have done wrongly here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5666/discussion-between-adarsh-k-and-luciano-mammino)

Comment: match returns an array of the matched subpatternes. If you want to have a boolean value you should do this way: `pattern.test(emailId)` ... This way it returns `true` in case of match and `false` otherwise

Comment: Okay:) got it finally, didnt know the exact usage of match, test fits in better for me,:) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = /^\w+@something.com$/;

reg.test("adarsh.k@something.com")
> true

reg.test("adarsh.k@gmail.com")
> false
```

**Edit :** Seems like I misunderstood your question...
The correct regex is :

```
var validDomain = "something";
var pattern = new RegExp("([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])"+"@" + validDomain + "(.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$");
```

Comment: Well, I need this to be returning false for all domains except "something.com", is it possible in this way?

Comment: This regex will return true only if the domain is 'something.com'

Comment: If at all, my requirement says it should be something.com and not any other like .net, .org etc, can i update the validDomain = "something.com" and remove the last part of the Reg expression? will that work?

Comment: Yes it will work, but my first regex did too... Why didn't you accept it ?

Comment: Well, I am not sure about the requirement yet, hence will decide which of the two patterns to use once I am clear on that. Thanks